# Difference between nested anova coded with "/" and linear mixed model with nested random factors

Tags: mixed-model, anova, nested-models

I'm trying to analyze data where site is nested within habitat which is then nested within region. Site is a random variable, but habitat should technically be fixed based on how the study was designed.

What is the difference in coding this analysis as:

1.nest= lm(logDen ~ Region/Habitat/Site , data=data)

Anova(nest, type=2)

versus

2. nest2 = lme(logDen ~ Region, random = ~1|Habitat/Site, method = "REML", data= data)

anova.lme(nest3, type = "marginal", adjustSigma = TRUE)